# How to create a UITableView that can scroll horizontally?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5, storyboard

I am trying to create a verticalTableView that has a horizontalTableView inside each verticalTableViewCell that can scroll horizontally (same concept as the 'Pulse' app). And I have found a number of tutorials (two examples below), but they are all in the days of XIBs.  Can anyone explain how to do it/give me a link to a tutorial on how to do the same with a Storyboard instead?

[First Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4680/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1)

[Second Tutorial](http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/creating-pulse-style-scrolling-horizontally-scrolling-uitableview-as-a-subview-of-uitableviewcell/)

Update:  I have since found another question on SO that was answered by the same person that asked the question. This person has managed to implement the protocols for a tableView using a UITableViewCell class, question is how? And does it matter that the tableView that contains the dynamic tableView is static?

[dynamic UITableView in static UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120424/dynamic-uitableview-in-static-uitableviewcell)

Comment: Tutorial for create table with storboard
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Xcode_Storyboards_to_Build_Dynamic_TableViews_with_Prototype_Table_View_Cells

and 

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_an_Xcode_Storyboard_to_Create_a_Static_Table_View

Comment: This tutorial does show how to get a UITableViewCell to define the behaviors of a prototype cell in a UITableViewController.  The part that I still need help with is how to get an entire UITableView (that goes horizontally) inside that UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @christoph, I finally figured it out. See sample code in his question.

[dynamic UITableView in static UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120424/dynamic-uitableview-in-static-uitableviewcell/10410463#comment14208216_10410463)

Answer (score 4):

Use the below part of code to create the required table.

```
    UITableView *horizontalTable = [[UITableView alloc] init];
    [horizontalTable setDelegate:self];
    [horizontalTable setDataSource:self];
    horizontalTable.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI * 0.5);
    horizontalTable.autoresizesSubviews=NO;
 frame =CGRectMake(140, 0 , 642, 85);
//frame is important this has to be set accordingly. if we did not set it properly, tableview will not appear some times in the view
[self.view addSubview:customTable];
```

and in the custom cell's CustomCell Class, we find the below method.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
```

in that method, 
use this.

```
 self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 0.5);
```

Comment: Where am I supposed to put the first snippet of code? Inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` of the verticalTable?

Comment: NO You have to put it on VIewDidLoad or some where else, where you want to add the horiz table