# Collectionview or tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, collections

[image]

Is there any way to achieve a view like this in ios?
There will be infinity scrolling in each row, how to achieve something like this? Is it using collectionview? and How can it be done? Any suggestion?

Comment: Table view and in every row of table view he is using collection view

Comment: You can use UICollectionView with Supplementary Views, Views having UICollectionView inside.

Comment: in here you need to use both

Comment: Is there any similar tutorial or github framework i can use for this?

Comment: please check option 3 of my answer below for github link

Comment: must be collection view

Answer (score 1):

You need to use table view and in every cell of table view you need to use a collection view please look on this [Link](https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell/) and this [Link as well](https://github.com/DahanHu/DHCollectionTableView)

Answer (score 1):

**OPTION 1:**

You can use one `uicollectionview` for each sub-category that will scroll horizontally using `UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39946022/creating-a-horizontal-scrolling-collectionview-in-swift#39951962) is a link that may be useful.

**OPTION 2:**

You can use one single `uitableview` for the whole page with header (section) saying the sub-category title and 'view all' button.

To scroll `uitableview` horizontally please check these links: 
[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185446/horizontal-uiscrollview-inside-custom-uitableviewcell-using-ib-storyboard-no) and [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779032/how-to-create-a-uitableview-that-can-scroll-horizontally).

**OPTION 3:**

You can try `GitHub` example [PTEHorizontalTableView](https://github.com/PTEz/PTEHorizontalTableView). Use this `tableview` with header.